# El rendimiento de mi juego baja al publicarlo en Google Play

Tags: unity3d, google-play

He desarrollado un sencillo juego en Unity para la plataforma Android. Si compilo e importo el APK a mi dispositivo el juego funciona a la perfección, pero si lo publico y lo descargo de la tienda de Google el rendimiento baja de manera considerable, bajando mucho los FPS, siendo este el mismo juego.

Os paso captura de los "player settings" por si pudiese ayudar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También os dejo link a la APP en la tienda de Google:
[Google Play: Johnny Jumper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ToniMarquez.JohnnyJumper&hl=es)

¿Alguna sugerencia? Gracias por adelantado.

[EDITADO]
*Si me lo ponéis en espera, decir al menos que es lo que no os queda claro de mi pregunta, así podré saber como solventarlo...*

Comment: Sinceramente yo creo que es una buena pregunta, quizá por qué no hay código *pueden pensar* que no está claro lo que se pregunta pero creo que está claro.

Comment: Si pongo código, ¿que parte del código? no son precisamente 4 lineas... el tema es que no debería ser problema del código, sino de la configuración (eso creo yo), ya que el juego va perfectamente si no pasa por el proceso de publicación. La verdad es que no tengo ni idea de que puede ser.

Comment: Esta pregunta está siendo evaluada por la comunidad en [meta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/743/227).

Comment: Si se puede reproducir lo que dices encuentro la pregunta extremadamente interesante. Podrías tratar de compilar lo más informaciones que posible sobre tu caso particular? Espero que la pregunta se puede mantener y resolver en alguna forma.